# SQL Server running out of space on large drive

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016-express

I've got a VB.Net program that updates an SQL Server 2008R2 database.

The disk is using 86.2Gb of 126Gb so there's lots of free space.

[image]

The autogrowth is set, as you can see, but I get the following error message on various threads:

Could not allocate space for object 'sys.syscolpars'.'nc' in database 'MyDB' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

The MDF file is currently 9Gb in size.

If Autogrowth is set, and there'e sufficient disk space, why is this happening?

EDIT:

OK, further testing has provided the following...

The SQL server in this case is not 2008R2 as suspected, but 2014 SQLExpress... sorry for the bum steer on that; I got my servers mixed up...

When I try this on a 2008R2 set up exactly the same, it seems to work ok without producing the error message.

So, the question seems to be is SQLexpress limited in size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Primary Filegroup is Full" in SQL Server 2008 Standard for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951647/primary-filegroup-is-full-in-sql-server-2008-standard-for-no-apparent-reason)

Comment: I defragged the drive, deleted the database and re-created it from scratch so that doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: There is more than one answer to that question. Please don't focus only on accepted answers; they tend to indicate only what was most helpful to that particular user at that point in time. There are also several other questions here that contain the same (or a very similar) error message that offer other possible solutions. Your first effort should be to search here and via Google for existing information before posting here.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33700

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size for the MDF file on SQL Express 2014 is currently 10GB so I imagine its trying to grow above that.

If you review the **Cross-Box Scale Limits** section (Maximum relational database size) with [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx) you will see why.